# How to apply multiple transform in SCSS using mixins?

Tags: html, sass, transform

How can I apply more than one transform in SCSS using mixins? I want translate and rotate transform in button. I used mixins for transform.

```css
@mixin transition($transition...) {
  /* defining prefixes so we can use them in mixins below*/
  $prefixes:      ("-webkit", "-ms", "-o",  "");
  @each $prefix in $prefixes {
    #{$prefix}-transition: $transition;
  }

  transition: $transition;
}
@mixin transform($transforms) {
  -moz-transform: $transforms;
  -o-transform: $transforms;
  -ms-transform: $transforms;
  -webkit-transform: $transforms;
  transform: $transforms;
}

// translate
@mixin translate ($x, $y) {
  @include transform(translate($x, $y));
}
// rotate
@mixin rotate ($deg) {
  @include transform(rotate(#{$deg}deg));
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid green;;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size:15px;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  min-width: 130px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position:relative;
  text-align: text-center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  @include transition(all 0.5s ease 0s);
  overflow: hidden;
  
  &:after {
    background: green;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
    @include transition(all 0.3s ease 0s);
  }
  
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
    
    &:after {
      height: 260%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Button</button>
```

Working Demo Here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MobqEQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, instead of writing this

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
```

just use your declared mixin directly,

```
@include transform(translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg));
```